# Dealing with input and output in Matlab

Tags: programming-challenge, io, matlab, set

I just wrote a program which performed some elementary set operations as you can see below. It's the first time I have used input and output of text files so I am mainly looking for critique on that, and also how I use cells.

```
clear all;
clc;

fileID = fopen('inputseto.txt','r');
data = textscan(fileID,'%s',3,'Delimiter','\n');
data = data{1,1};

n = data{1}
n = str2num(n);

A = data{2};
B = data{3};

A = str2num(A(2:end-1));
B = str2num(B(2:end-1));

output = cell(1,6);

output{1} = union(A,B);
output{2} = intersect(A,B);
output{3} = setdiff(A,B);
output{4} = setdiff(B,A);
output{5} = setdiff(1:n,A);
output{6} = setdiff(1:n,B);

fileID = fopen('outputseto.txt','w');

for i = 1:6
    fprintf(fileID,'{'); 
    fprintf(fileID,'%d, ',output{i}(1:end-1));
    if i ~= 6
        fprintf(fileID,'%d}\n',output{i}(end));
    else
        fprintf(fileID,'%d}',output{i}(end));
    end
end
```

I got this problem from [here](http://rosalind.info/problems/seto/). The input is 3 lines, the first lines describes the global set. The first line is an integer n and the global set is the set containing 1,2,...,n. Then the next two lines are two sets A and B. The output consists of various set operations involving A and B.  The solution is correct, but I feel like some of this code doesn't "feel right". I am interested in knowing what you think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that I see is that the files are not closed with `fclose` after the data is read/written.  Especially using the same variable (`fileID`) as the file handle for the second while the first is still open (effectively losing the first one). Although you can still always do `fclose('all')` and I think it would close even those files still open that don't have a handle still assigned.